# How to use substitutions

Tags: tcl

How to search each string word and change it as like below;

```
set firstLibrary {12345}
set secondLibrary {aghij}
```

Remarks:

```
1=a ; 2=g ; 3=h ; 4=i ; 5=j
```

```
set theString {44168}
```

then the output is; `44168 = iia68`

Comment: The question is unclear, please add more details

Comment: Take a look at [string map](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M34) in the documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to assemble those two libraries into a map that you can use with `string map`. The key to this is that you can use the two-list form of `foreach`, and the `split` command can easily break a string into its component characters if the separator set is empty.

```
set map {}
foreach from [split $firstLibrary ""] to [split $secondLibrary ""] {
    lappend map $from $to
}
```

Applying the map with `string map` to `$theString` and printing the result is left as an exercise.

Comment: Its great. One more, how to split a string two word from the sttring. For example: {helloworlds} and output is: he ll ow or ld s

Comment: @Andre That'd be something for regexp: `regexp -all -inline {..?} "helloworlds"`